# MySQL: Find nearest polygon for each point

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
1 table with points, and
1 table with polygons.

I am looking for a query that joins on the nearest polygon for each point.

The `points` table looks like this:

```
|-id-|-name-|-location---|
|====|======|============|
|-1--|-A----|-POINT(1 0)-|
|-2--|-B----|-POINT(3 4)-|
|-3--|-C----|-POINT(2 9)-|
|-4--|-D----|-POINT(6 2)-|
```

The `polygons` table looks like this:

```
|-id-|-name-|-area---------------------|
|====|======|==========================|
|-1--|-A----|-POLYGON(1 0,3 4,2 9,1 0)-|
|-2--|-B----|-POLYGON(3 4,2 9,6 2,3 4)-|
|-3--|-C----|-POLYGON(2 9,6 2,1 0,2 9)-|
|-4--|-D----|-POLYGON(6 2,1 0,3 4,6 2)-|
```

The preferred output of this query would be something like this: (dummy data)

```
|-id-|-name-|-location---|-id-|-name-|-area---------------------|
|====|======|============|====|======|==========================|
|-1--|-A----|-POINT(1 0)-|-2--|-B----|-POLYGON(3 4,2 9,6 2,3 4)-|
|-2--|-B----|-POINT(3 4)-|-3--|-C----|-POLYGON(2 9,6 2,1 0,2 9)-|
|-3--|-C----|-POINT(2 9)-|-2--|-B----|-POLYGON(3 4,2 9,6 2,3 4)-|
|-4--|-D----|-POINT(6 2)-|-1--|-A----|-POLYGON(1 0,3 4,2 9,1 0)-|
```

**(EDIT: Simply execute the following .sql to create this schema: https://gist.github.com/badeend/dfdf826a1afbeeac5866be286a9bd30e)**

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT *, ST_DISTANCE(points.point, polygons.polygon) FROM points INNER JOIN polygons
```

But that returns the distance for all polygons, instead of only the nearest.

Comment: Please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE [your_table]` and some example data op http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added an .sql with example data. sqlfiddle.com wouldn't accept my SQL because the binary data makes it too large.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is the use the ordere by and limit

```
SELECT *, ST_DISTANCE(points.point, polygons.polygon) 
FROM points INNER JOIN polygons
order by ST_DISTANCE(points.point, polygons.polygon)  asc limit 1
```

but you could use also aggregation function like min()

You should also assign explicit condition forn join  using eg:  on points.col = polygons.col

Comment: This does not return the minimum ST_DISTANCE per point. 
Also, using GROUP BY and MIN _will_ return the minimum distance, but not the associated polygon row, which is what I am after.

Comment: The minimun should be returned with asc (and not desc).. if you want use the min you can't obtain al the column directly but selecting the rows that match .. let me know